# How to Verify a Google API JWT with Firebase\JWT (Oauth) in PHP

Tags: php, jwt, google-oauth

How can I decode a JWT generated by Google using Firebase JWT in PHP?

I am trying to decode a JWT from Google API in a PHP endpoint:

```
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT; 

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secret, array('RS256'));
```

However, I get the error: "OpenSSL error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"

I can't get the jwt to be verified at jwt.io, either:
[image: Unable to verify Google JWT]

[image: This is where I got the secret from]

I am able to decode my own HS256 JWTs using this method without any problems.

Comment: to verify a RS256 signed token you don't need a secret, but a public key. Please use the search function, I'm sure that topic has been asked and answered before

Comment: @jps if it has please link to the question.

Answer (score 1):

`composer require google/apiclient`

`use Google\AccessToken\Verify;`

```
$verify = new Verify();
$payload = $verify->verifyIdToken($request->google_token);
```